# Как сохранять данные пользователя в mysql?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql, telegram-bot, aiogram, mysqlconnector

Как можно сделать сохранение каких либо данных телеграмм пользователя в таблицу mysql (например сохранить message.text/id/username)? Я знаю только как создавать/удалять датабазы через питон. Как можно это реализовать с помощью mysql.connector, aiogram, getpass? Базовый код mysql для создания/удаления датабаз:

```
from getpass import getpass
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
import os
from time import sleep as sp

while True:
    try:
        with connect(
            host="localhost",
            user=input("Введите имя пользователя: "),
            password=getpass("Введите пароль: "),
    )     as connection:
            os.system("clear")
            a = input("Создать датабазу? y/n/d: ")
            if a == "y":
                os.system("clear")
                create_db_query = f"CREATE DATABASE {input('Имя датабазы: ')}"
                show_db_query = "SHOW DATABASES"
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(create_db_query)
                    cursor.execute(show_db_query)
                    for db in cursor:
                        print(db)
                sp(3)
                os.system("clear")
            elif a == "d":
                os.system("clear")
                drop_db_query = f"DROP DATABASE {input('Имя датабазы: ')}"
                os.system("clear")
                show_db_query = "SHOW DATABASES"
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(drop_db_query)
                    cursor.execute(show_db_query)
                    for db in cursor:
                        print(db)
                sp(3)
                os.system("clear")
            else:
                os.system("clear")
                show_db_query = "SHOW DATABASES"
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(show_db_query)
                    for db in cursor:
                        print(db)
                sp(3)
                os.system("clear")
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
        sp(3)
        os.system("clear")
```

Хотелось бы что нибудь такого типа, но с aiogram.

Comment: «Я знаю только как создавать/удалять датабазы» — значит возьмите любой учебник по sql и изучите базовые sql-команды

Comment: Да, тут надо азы SQL сначала изучить.

Comment: Азы я могу изучить, тут я не уверен в совместимости, я так пытался input() текст отправить по tcp в итоге несколько дней пытался пофиксить, т.к. отправить можно только байты.

Comment: `SQL` универсален, по крайней мере в азах. Если вы выучите `SELECT` и `INSERT`, они примерно одинаково будут работать в любой `SQL` базе данных.